# Neural Network implementation in java

Tags: java, neural-network, backpropagation, feed-forward

I am attempting to implement a FFNN in Java with backpropagation and have no idea what I am doing wrong. It worked when I had only a single neuron in the network, but I wrote another class to handle larger networks and nothing converges. It seems like a problem in the math - or rather my implementation of the math - but I've checked it several times and I can't find anything wrong. This should be working.
Node class:

```
package arr;

import util.ActivationFunction;
import util.Functions;

public class Node {
    public ActivationFunction f;
    public double output;
    public double error;

    private double sumInputs;
    private double sumErrors;
    public Node(){
        sumInputs = 0;
        sumErrors = 0;
        f = Functions.SIG;
        output = 0;
        error = 0;
    }
    public Node(ActivationFunction func){
        this();
        this.f = func;
    }

    public void addIW(double iw){
        sumInputs += iw;
    }
    public void addIW(double input, double weight){
        sumInputs += (input*weight);
    }
    public double calculateOut(){
        output = f.eval(sumInputs);
        return output;
    }

    public void addEW(double ew){
        sumErrors+=ew;
    }
    public void addEW(double error, double weight){
        sumErrors+=(error*weight);
    }
    public double calculateError(){
        error = sumErrors * f.deriv(sumInputs);
        return error;
    }   
    public void resetValues(){
        sumErrors = 0;
        sumInputs = 0;
    }
}
```

LineNetwork class:

```
package arr;
import util.Functions;

public class LineNetwork {
public double[][][] weights;    //layer of node to, # of node to, # of node from
public Node[][] nodes;          //layer, #
public double lc;
public LineNetwork(){
    weights = new double[2][][];
    weights[0] = new double[2][1];
    weights[1] = new double[1][3];
    initializeWeights();
    nodes = new Node[2][];
    nodes[0] = new Node[2];
    nodes[1] = new Node[1];
    initializeNodes();
    lc = 1;
}
private void initializeWeights(){
    for(double[][] layer: weights)
        for(double[] curNode: layer)
            for(int i=0; i<curNode.length; i++)
                curNode[i] = Math.random()/10;
}
private void initializeNodes(){
    for(Node[] layer: nodes)
        for(int i=0; i<layer.length; i++)
            layer[i] = new Node();
    nodes[nodes.length-1][0].f = Functions.HSF;
}
public double feedForward(double[] inputs) {
    for(int j=0; j<nodes[0].length; j++)
        nodes[0][j].addIW(inputs[j], weights[0][j][0]);
    double[] outputs = new double[nodes[0].length];
    for(int i=0; i<nodes[0].length; i++)
        outputs[i] = nodes[0][i].calculateOut();
    for(int l=1; l<nodes.length; l++){
        for(int i=0; i<nodes[l].length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<nodes[l-1].length; j++)
                nodes[l][i].addIW(
                        outputs[j], 
                        weights[l][i][j]);
            nodes[l][i].addIW(weights[l][i][weights[l][i].length-1]);
        }
        outputs = new double[nodes[l].length];
        for(int i=0; i<nodes[l].length; i++)
            outputs[i] = nodes[l][i].calculateOut();
    }
    return outputs[0];
}

public void backpropagate(double[] inputs, double expected) {
    nodes[nodes.length-1][0].addEW(expected-nodes[nodes.length-1][0].output);
    for(int l=nodes.length-2; l>=0; l--){
        for(Node n: nodes[l+1])
            n.calculateError();
        for(int i=0; i<nodes[l].length; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<nodes[l+1].length; j++)
                nodes[l][i].addEW(nodes[l+1][j].error, weights[l+1][j][i]);
        for(int j=0; j<nodes[l+1].length; j++){
            for(int i=0; i<nodes[l].length; i++)
                weights[l+1][j][i] += nodes[l][i].output*lc*nodes[l+1][j].error;
            weights[l+1][j][nodes[l].length] += lc*nodes[l+1][j].error;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<nodes[0].length; i++){
        weights[0][i][0] += inputs[i]*lc*nodes[0][i].calculateError();
    }
}
public double train(double[] inputs, double expected) {
    double r = feedForward(inputs);
    backpropagate(inputs, expected);
    return r;
}
public void resetValues() {
    for(Node[] layer: nodes)
        for(Node n: layer)
            n.resetValues();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LineNetwork ln = new LineNetwork();
    System.out.println(str2d(ln.weights[0]));
    for(int i=0; i<10000; i++){
        double[] in = {Math.round(Math.random()),Math.round(Math.random())};
        int out = 0;
        if(in[1]==1 ^ in[0] ==1) out = 1;
        ln.resetValues();
        System.out.print(i+": {"+in[0]+", "+in[1]+"}: "+out+" ");
        System.out.println((int)ln.train(in, out));
    }
    System.out.println(str2d(ln.weights[0]));
}
private static String str2d(double[][] a){
    String str = "[";
    for(double[] arr: a)
        str = str + str1d(arr) + ",\n";
    str = str.substring(0, str.length()-2)+"]";
    return str;
}
private static String str1d(double[] a){
    String str = "[";
    for(double d: a)
        str = str+d+", ";
    str = str.substring(0, str.length()-2)+"]";
    return str;
}
}
```

Quick explanation of structure: every node has an activation function f; `f.eval` evaluates the function and `f.deriv` evaluates its derivative. `Functions.SIG` is the standard sigmoidal function and `Functions.HSF` is the Heaviside step function. In order to set the inputs of a function, you call `addIW` with a value that already includes the weight of the previous output. A similar thing is done in backpropagation with `addEW`. Nodes are organized in a 2d array and weights are organized separately in a 3d array as described.

I realize this may be a bit much to ask - and I certainly realize how many Java conventions this code breaks - but I appreciate any help anyone can offer.

EDIT: Since this question and my code are such giant walls of text, if there's a line involving lots of complicated expressions in brackets that you don't want to figure out, add a comment or something asking me and I'll try to answer it as quickly as I can.

EDIT 2: The specific problem here is that this network doesn't converge on XOR. Here's some output to illustrate this:

> 9995: {1.0, 0.0}: 1 1 
>   9996: {0.0, 1.0}: 1 1 
>   9997: {0.0, 0.0}: 0 1 
>   9998: {0.0, 1.0}: 1 0 
>   9999: {0.0, 1.0}: 1 1 
>   Each line is of the format `TEST NUMBER: {INPUTS}: EXPECTED ACTUAL`
>   The network calls `train` with each test, so this network is backpropagating 10000 times.

Here are the two extra classes if anyone wants to run it:

```
package util;

public class Functions {
public static final ActivationFunction LIN = new ActivationFunction(){
            public double eval(double x) {
                return x;
            }

            public double deriv(double x) {
                return 1;
            }
};
public static final ActivationFunction SIG = new ActivationFunction(){
            public double eval(double x) {
                return 1/(1+Math.exp(-x));
            }

            public double deriv(double x) {
                double ev = eval(x);
                return ev * (1-ev);
            }
};
public static final ActivationFunction HSF = new ActivationFunction(){
            public double eval(double x) {
                if(x>0) return 1;
                return 0;
            }

            public double deriv(double x) {
                return (1);
            }
};
}

package util;

public interface ActivationFunction {
public double eval(double x);
public double deriv(double x);
}
```

Now it's even longer. Darn.

Comment: What is the specific problem? What is the expected result? Can you make a shorter program to reproduce it? As it stands now I vote to close this due to "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. "

Comment: If you can train a single neuron, the problem is likely in your backpropagate method. Have you tried a "by hand" calculation with a small net to compare it to? 

It would also help if you could post the missing classes so your code could be run.

Comment: @KErlandsson : I added the specific problem, I'll look into a shorter program but it'll certainly take time as I'm not entirely sure what isn't working and what I'll therefore be able to take out.

Comment: @jbkm : I changed some things and the code, if you put all of it in, should now be runnable. I was afraid to try a by hand calculation earlier because it was 5 layers but now that it's 2 I'll try.

Comment: if you're mad enough, you can review this implementation and try to find the differences  https://github.com/AdamSkywalker/btc-indexer/blob/master/src/com/ssau/btc/model/MLP.java

Comment: @jbkm I did a small by hand calculation with a few cases and everything seems to be in order. I think I'm missing something more fundamental. I am supposed to include the previous output in the delta weight, right? Is using the Heaviside step function as the last neuron output bad practice? Am I handling the derivatives of the activation functions like I should be?

Answer (score 1):

In your main method:

```
double[] in = {Math.round(Math.random()),Math.round(Math.random())};
int out = 0;
if(in[1]==1 ^ in[0] ==1) out = 1;
```

You create a random input (combination of 1 and 0) that receives target 0. Since `Math.random` has a specific internal seed (there is no true randomness) you are not able to guarantee that over 10000 iterations all 4 inputs of XOR are generated by a balanced amount with this technique. This in turn means that it is possible that in 10000 iterations `{0.0,0.0}` was only trained a couple hundred times while `{1.0,0.0}` `{0.0,1.0}` was trained about 8000 times. If this is the case, this would clearly explain your results and limit your training.

Instead of randomly **generating** your input data, randomly **pick** from it. Keep the outer (epochs) loop and introduce a 2nd loop where you pick a random sample that you have **not** picked in this epoch yet (or simply go through your data sequentially without any randomness, it's not really an issue for XOR). Pseudocode without any randomness:

```
// use a custom class to realize the data structure (that defines the target values):
TrainingSet = { {(0,0),0}, {(0,1),1}, {(1,0),1}, {(1,1),0} } 
for epochNr < epochs:
    while(TrainingSet.hasNext()):
        input = TrainingSet.getNext();
        network.feedInput(input)
```

This way you can guarantee that each sample is seen 2500 times in 10000 iterations.

Comment: I did the sequential method and it didn't work; depending on learning constant and number of iterations, the network trained to a predictable sequence - but not a correct one. One time it got every one exactly wrong, another time it had everything shifted over one - the network itself isn't converging.